# Can someone give an overview of the various choices on GCloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm a bit confused as to understanding the various offerings that google cloud has.

Is it basically like this:

1. Google app engine is fully managed servers, you push the code and it runs.
2. They have a servers that you manage yourself, you choose the sizes and spin them up and push code manually
3. Servers that run docker containers for you.

Is that a high level offering of google cloud **in terms of the application servers**?  (excluding their managed services for db, caching etc).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/choosing-a-compute-option

There are also cloud functions that belong to the compute group of GCP:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/